# Using QAction with QLabel and creating accordion using QStackedWidget

Tags: pyqt

I am trying to add QAction object to QLabel object using QLabel.addAction() method, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it not supposed to work or am I doing something wrong?

I am trying to make an accordion using QStackedWidget.

[image]

For this I need a section title which will either hide or show the title's section when user presses on that title. I could use mouseReleasedEvent, but I would prefer proper QAction toggle() implementation. Maybe I could use something else than QLabel for this matter?

Comment: While reading about events accidently I found out that you can use label (widget) actions for context menu. You just need to set up ContextMenu Policy like that: label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu) Unfortunately that's not wanted use of Actions. It looks that I will need to define my own custom widget in order to create accordion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `addAction` functionality of `QWidget` is used for providing context menus and does not directly relate to an action that is triggered when the mouse is clicked on the label.

You therefore must use some kind of mousexxxevent.

If you prefer signals instead, this is also quite easy:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class ClickableLabel(QLabel):
    """
        A Label that emits a signal when clicked.
    """

    clicked = Signal()

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

# example
app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
labelA = ClickableLabel('Click on me for more.')
layout.addWidget(labelA)
labelB = QLabel('Here I am.')
layout.addWidget(labelB)
labelB.hide()
labelA.clicked.connect(labelB.show)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Or if you want an action instead, make it like this:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class ClickableLabel(QLabel):
    """
        A Label that emits a signal when clicked.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.action.triggered.emit()

# example
app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
labelA = ClickableLabel('Click on me for more.')
layout.addWidget(labelA)
labelB = QLabel('Here I am.')
layout.addWidget(labelB)
labelB.hide()

action = QAction('Action', labelA)
labelA.action = action
action.triggered.connect(labelB.show)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

The example are in Python 3.X notation and for PySide but translation to Python 2.X or PyQt is probably quite simple.